# is there any google earth widget for gwt

Tags: gwt, google-earth

[the sample here](http://code.google.com/p/earth-api-samples/source/browse/trunk/demos/gwt-earth/) is from 2008 and it doesn't work for me...
i tried gwt-maps widget but the kml overlay doesn't work on the earth view

i need a gwt widget that displays google earth plugin on the browser and provide the api to load kml (kmz) file and display models from sketchup

is there any solution available? or do i have to work with native javascript to create the widget?

Answer (score 3):

I am in the process of [wrapping the entire earth API v3](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-earth-3/).

Comment: Any updates from anyone on this?

Nick - I've been looking for a good wrapper of the Google Earth API to use in GWT, is your project the only one? I noticed it looks fairly new, and judging from this post it looks like it might still be under rapid development.

I'd love to use it, but am timid of newly written APIs that might change in the future (as all do) given the new age of the gwt-earth-3 wrapper.